# Images are mobile responsive but are not responsive on Desktop

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using React components and have been trying to make a carousel with 3 images but the issue is it's responsive on mobile but as soon as I view it on my desktop, the images look almost stretched out, for example I have an image of an a sunny-side-up egg toast, and it looks good on my 'responsive' settings under dev tools but if i expand on my desktop I can mostly see the egg yolk.

Here is my CSS. and any help appreciated!

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  --heights: 50vh;
  --widths: 100%;
}

.slider-container {
  height: var(--heights);
  width: var(--widths);
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

.inactive {
  display: none;
}

.slides {
  height: var(--heights);
  width: var(--widths);
}

.slide-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slide-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.slide-text {
  top: 35%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: -3rem;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  color: #84a98c;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.all-dots {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: 85%;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 200;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active-dot,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #84a98c;
}
```

Here is my JSX

```
const len = sliderImage.length - 1;

const Slider = (props) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setActiveIndex(activeIndex === len ? 0 : activeIndex + 1);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [activeIndex]);

  return (
    <div className="slider-container">
      <SliderContent activeIndex={activeIndex} sliderImage={sliderImage} />
      <Arrows
        prevSlide={() =>
          setActiveIndex(activeIndex < 1 ? len : activeIndex - 1)
        }
        nextSlide={() =>
          setActiveIndex(activeIndex === len ? 0 : activeIndex + 1)
        }
      />
      <Dots
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        sliderImage={sliderImage}
        onclick={(activeIndex) => setActiveIndex(activeIndex)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you aren't choosing one axis to scale your image. If you scale with both it ignore the original images ratio and does what you ask making it 50vw by 50vh. In this case width is going to be the more useful axis (i think) .

The problem is probably here in this css selector:

```
.slides {
  height: var(--heights);
  width: var(--widths);
}
```

either use just:

```
.slides {
    width: var(--widths);
}
```

or just use:

```
.slides {
  height: var(--heights);
}
```

also in your root tag change the value of width (or height accordingly in view port lengths):

```
:root {
  --widths: 75vw;
}
```

*If none of this works show me the jsx, im working in the dark here guessing what these classes mean*

Comment: None of it worked unfortunately, i tried all your recommendations, ill add the JSX to my original post, thanks.

Comment: I think you need to show us the jsx that goes with it

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is
`object-fit:cover` because this stretches the image to fit in the parent element.

Comment: i took this away and also changed it up, and it made all the images worse.

Comment: Then I think u should use an image that fit in desktop mode, so when you switch to mobile it will fit according to screen. Image is stretching in desktop cause the size is small but when u use image, size of your desktop mode than it will work fine. give it a try